# Javascript error, toggle property not working as required

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#p1").click(function() {
            $("#Menu_Div").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

is working fine, but when i replace it with the code as shown below by changing the toggle property, it does nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#p1").click(function() {
            $("#Menu_Div").toggle( "slide","left","slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

is not working.
"#Menu_Div" is the Id for  and "#p1" is the id for another div.

Comment: If what you want is toggle some classes in `#Menu_Div`you should be using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the animate method

```
$("#Menu_Div").animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
```

Comment: $("#Menu_Div").animate({width:'toggle'},1000);  it worked,

Comment: $(function () {
            $("#p1").click(function () {$("#slidediv").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 100);
            }); this metod works fine, but what if i want to use slide property, i have tried  $(function () {
            $("#p1").click(function () {
                $('#slidediv').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700);
            }); but this doesn't worked forme.